# Can a set have more than one ultrafilter?

Tags: filters

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Ultrafilter_on_Set

Given the definition that a filter $\mathcal F $ on a set $\mathcal S$ is  an ultrafilter on $\mathcal S$ iff there is no filter on  $\mathcal S$ which is strictly finer than $\mathcal F$, doesn't that just mean that the only ultrafilter on a set $\mathcal S$ is simply $\mathcal {P(S)} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$, the power set of $\mathcal S$ with the empty set removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a filter (it's not closed under intersection unless $S$ has one element).

Every set $S$ has at least $|S|$ many ultrafilters, namely, for any $s \in S$ the *principal ultrafilter* given by the subsets containing $s$. These are the only ultrafilters when $S$ is finite. When $S$ is infinite there are (assuming the axiom of choice) [non-principal ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Types_and_existence_of_ultrafilters), which let you do lots of fun stuff.

Comment: Ok, looks like I need some more experience with this then. I'm self studying set theory and I've never had a topology class, so I'll just need to get more experience with this. Please feel free to suggest any good books or resources, especially ones with good examples to make it specific, since it's quite abstract. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Hank: there's a nice intuitive way to think about ultrafilters in terms of "voting systems" which connects the "every ultrafilter on a finite set is principal" result to Arrow's impossibility theorem: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/ultrafilters-nonstandard-analysis-and-epsilon-management/

Comment: If you've taken abstract algebra, here is the easiest algebraic definition: an ultrafilter on a set $S$ is (the same data as) a ring homomorphism $\prod_S \mathbb{F}_2 \to \mathbb{F}_2$. When $S$ is finite the only such homomorphisms are the projections and when $S$ is infinite more weird stuff can happen.